# how to integrate GitHub authentication in android app

Tags: android, github

I want to authenticate my android app through GitHub account. I did not find any documentation for this. Please tell me if someone knows. How to do this?

Comment: You can go for **Firebase** Which provides a way to github authentication.

Comment: @NigamPatro is there any other way to github authentication directly like facebook & gmail?

Comment: You can try this link, https://developer.github.com/v3/. It's official Github Developer link. So, you just need to do API calls.

Comment: There is another Java Library https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core. You can try with that.

Comment: Thanks @NigamPatro. I will try these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, GitHub does not provide openID, but they do provide OAuth.

Check that out here: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Comment: So this is possible or not to authenticate my android app with github?

Comment: It is possible using OAuth.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge in using firebase you can. 
This link might help you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/github-auth